# Smallest integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I encountered an intriguing problem and I think I have a solution, but I want to run it by some of the smarter people around here:

Find the smallest integer $n, n>1$ such that $C(n)=n, C(n)$ is the total number of 1s that appear as you count from 1. For example, $C(9) = 1$, counting from $n=1$ to $n=9$, there is one 1. $C(99) =20, C(100)=21$, etc. I was able to get, as I stated, that from 1 to 99, there are 20 1s. From 1 to 199, $100 + 20*2$, up to 999 there are these $140 + 8*20 = 300$. Keeping with this algorithm I get $C(9,999)=4,000, C(99,999)=50,000$, and $C(199,999)=C(200,000)=200,000$

What I seem to be having trouble with is, is this the smallest integer for which $C(n)=n$?

Comment: It's $n=1$, maybe?

Comment: I'm sorry, that's n>1, not n>0. Let me fix that. Thanks!

Comment: $n = 199981$ seems to work. Project Euler [Problem 156](https://projecteuler.net/problem=156) seems to agree that this is the smallest such integer larger than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a simple brute-force program I see that the smallest such value is $n=199,981$ which makes sense.

Similarly you could backtrack from $200,000$ to see that at 10 less, $199,990$ also works, as well as every number below it down to $199,981$.

This is an interesting function, after $200,001$ there are no more results until $1,599,981$ at which point it does a few and jumps again to $2,600,000$ and continues to jump higher and higher, giving some strange values like $117,463,825$; I would initially assume that there would but I am now wondering if there's a maximum such $n$.

**Edit:**

OEIS never ceases to amaze me: http://oeis.org/A014778

It appears that it has been shown that there are only 84 such numbers (including 0 and 1) ending at $1,111,111,110$

Comment: Very interesting, indeed.